# Ambari - Horton HDP

Tags: ambari

I have installed HDP 2.0 on UBUNTU, and configured AMBARI. I restarted my machine 
and then logged on node1 using ssh node1, then started ambari server using command # ambari-server start.

I have logged on http://node1:8080 , but nothing is active and against every service i am receiving heartbeat lost.

I have tried restarting service but nothing happening. the image of current state of dash board is also attached here with.

Please help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check if all your **ambari-agents** are in the running state? Usually the services do not communicate when you do not have **ambari-agents** running on each of your host. If it still doesn't work then check your */etc/hosts* file on each of your host if it has all the nodes' entries. Let me know!